# How to create an ordered list in html with a decreasing index?

Tags: html

First of all, sorry if my question is bad or ridiculous, I am a beginner at web dev and excuse me please. I am currently working on a small web project that includes rating, and I am using ordered lists to do so. But the problem is that I didn't find anyway to make a decreasing index. What should i do please? Here is my code:

```
<ol type="1">
    <li>ten</li>
    <li>nine</li>
    <li>eight</li>
    <li>seven</li>
    <li>six</li>
    <li>five</li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>one</li>
</ol>
```

Thanks for advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `reversed` attribute

```
<ol type="1" reversed>
    <li>ten</li>
    <li>nine</li>
    <li>eight</li>
    <li>seven</li>
    <li>six</li>
    <li>five</li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>one</li>
 </ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `reversed` attribute?

Check out this tutorial on [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_ol_reversed.asp) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The ordered list allows users to setup multiple parameters:

**reversed**
This Boolean attribute specifies that the list’s items are in reverse order. Items will be numbered from high to low.

**start**
An integer to start counting from for the list items. Always an Arabic numeral (1, 2, 3, etc.), even when the numbering type is letters or Roman numerals. For example, to start numbering elements from the letter "d" or the Roman numeral "iv," use start="4".

**type**
Sets the numbering type:

a for lowercase letters

A for uppercase letters

i for lowercase Roman numerals

I for uppercase Roman numerals

1 for numbers (default)reversed

This Boolean attribute specifies that the list’s items are in reverse order. Items will be numbered from high to low.

in this case you have to simply add flag reversed like:

```html
<ol type="1" reversed>
  <li>ten</li>
  <li>nine</li>
  <li>eight</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `reversed` parameter to make descendant index.

```
<ol type="1" reversed>
    <li>ten</li>
    <li>nine</li>
    .
    .
    .
    <li>two</li>
    <li>one</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).